# Gmail blue bar (/current conversation indicator) not following clicks

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

Generally, the Gmail blue bar indicator or selector for keyboard shortcuts follows a click on the conversation's selection box. For some reason, it's stopped doing that in one of my accounts. This is very frustrating as I use keyboard shortcuts often, mostly around conversations that I interact with.

The GIF below illustrates one of my healthy accounts:

[image: blue selection bar follows clicks]

This one is the account with the blue bar not following selection clicks. Note that keyboard shortcuts are activated, as evidenced by the fact that I use them during the screen recording here:

[image: blue selection bar does not follow clicks]

Any pointers on what might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

The "Multiple Inboxes" advanced setting covered in [this Google help article](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9282966?hl=en) has the side-effect of disabling the usual blue bar behaviour.

Disable the Gmail/G Suite advanced option of Multiple Inboxes to make sure the blue bar follows the latest click, as expected.